# My constraint foreign key is not working on my database

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb

```
create table students (StudentId int primary key not null);

create table records (
     RecordId int primary key not null,
     StudentId int not null,
     constraint fk foreign key(StudentId) references students(StudentId));

 insert into students values (201810696);
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.120 sec)

 insert into records values (1011, 20181313);
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.004 sec)
```

Why it keeps on accepting values that are not existing in table students?? I've already set my storage engine to innoDb on both of my tables in phpmyadmin localhost operations

btw I'm using the latest version of wampp and coding in cmd

Comment: which db engine?

Comment: Didn't old versions of Innodb just silently ignore fk's?

Comment: I've set it to innoDb

Comment: I think you should double-check. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE students\G` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE records\G` and you will see the ENGINE for each.

Comment: Another possibility: `select @@foreign_key_checks;` to confirm that you have enforcement of FK's enabled. This will return `1` if it's enabled, and `0` if not.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table students (StudentId int primary key not null);

create table records (RecordId int primary key not null, StudentId int not null, constraint fk 
foreign key(StudentId) references students(StudentId));

insert into records values(1, 1);
```

I tried this in mysql 5.6, and insert is failed:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_9_cd6353`.`records`, CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`StudentId`) REFERENCES `students` (`StudentId`))
```

You must be having corresponding data in Primary Table which you missed.

Comment: ya I've already inserted a value in students table, but once I've entered non existing values in students table the records table accepts it with no error. like 
insert into students values (201810696);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.120 sec)

MariaDB [library]> insert into records values (1011, 20181313);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.004 sec)